# Laravel Login route not working - submit button doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am implementing authentication in my Laravel application, the register and logout routes are working perfectly fine, but the login form is not working. I'm not getting any error, but when I click the logi button it doesn't go anywhere.

Here is my login.blade.php :

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Login')
@section('content')
<form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}>
    @csrf
    <h3 class="text-center m-b-20">Sign In</h3>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input required="" id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="Enter your Email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus> </div>
            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" required>
            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-auto">
                    <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" id="to-recover" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fas fa-lock m-r-5"></i>{{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 p-b-20">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-rounded" type="submit">{{ __('Login') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group m-b-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            Don't have an account? <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="text-info m-l-5"><b>Sign Up</b></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@endsection
```

These are my login routes:

```html
$this->get('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Does anyone know where I messed up?

Comment: You named your GET route, not your POST route. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: Why are you having another route for the admin login? Use a middleware to access the admin panel and you'll have everything done already, no worries about a submit button not working.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? what happens when you run `php artisan route:list` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing the standard auth routing wrapped in a prefix to give you want you want:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

That way you do not have to worry about the route names being different from the docs :)

Comment: Nice and clean solution, however OP would need to add some custom validation in the login controller so normal users can't get in the admin panel.

Comment: You can make a middleware and declare it the Kernel.php and then have the group use the said middleware.

Comment: Tried it but nothing is changing

Comment: I just did it on a fresh instance of laravel and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The routing prefix is working, i mean the login button

Comment: The submit button? I created a new project with `larave new laravel`, then ran `php artisan make:auth` then adjusted the web.php as outlined above, ran a migration, and was able to login. Is your login button calling the named route?

Comment: As I stated in my question, only the login route is the one that is not working. the other routes are working perfect.

Comment: When i click the login button, it doesn't respond. I provided the codes above